# Optimization of sieve of Erathosthenes

Tags: c++, optimization, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <math.h>
    using namespace std;
    #define RUNS 1000
    char z[100000];
    int i,j,k,c;

    void main(void)
      {
      DWORD starttime,endtime;
      float totaltime;

      starttime = GetTickCount();//get start time
      for(k=0;k<RUNS;k++)
      {
          c=0; 

      //for (i=0;i<10000;i++) z[i]=0; //clear array
      memset(z,0,100000);
        z[0]=1; // 0 is not a prime
        z[1]=1;  // 1 is not a prime
            //now remove all evens from 4 up
            for(i=4;i<100000;i=i+2) z[i]=1; //remove evens
            //now loop through remaing up to square root of max number
            for(i=3;i<316;i=i+2)
            {
            if(z[i]==0) for(j=2*i;j<100000;j=j+i) z[j]=1;
            }
      }

      endtime=GetTickCount();//get finish time
      //calc time
      for(i=0;i<100000;i++)
      {
      if(z[i]==0) {cout<<i<<" ";c++;}
      }
      cout<<"primes found="<<c<<endl;
      totaltime=((float)endtime-(float)starttime)/(1000.0*RUNS);//calculate total time in secs
      cout<<"Totaltime="<<totaltime<<" sec\n";

      printf("Press any key to end");

      getch();
      }
```

1. I'm trying to find any optimization for my sieve of Eratosthenes code for counting first 100000 prime numbers.
2. The program first mark all even numbers, than square root of max number.
3. The program already does take fraction of the seconds to count these prime numbers, but I`m looking for any optimization to make it even quicker.

Comment: Man this comes up a lot. Think its an article I will have to write about :-)

Comment: Small optimization to your increment. Rather than 'i=i+2` You can use `i=i+2` one iteration followed by an `i=i+4` the next iteration (because every third increment of 2 is also divisible by 3). So: 5 -> 7 -> 11 -> 13 -> 17 -> 19 ... Basically this is equivalent to cutting out all 2 and 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (z[i] == 0)
    for (j = 2 * i; j < 100000; j = j + i)
        z[j] = 1;
```

can be changed to

```
if (z[i] == 0)
    for (j = i * i; j < 100000; j = j + 2 * i)
        z[j] = 1;
```

as

- `k * i` (with `k < i`) is already set to `1` by sieve `k`.
- when `j` is odd, `j + i` is even and so already set by even sieve.

For readability, you may split into function and do some renaming, to have something like:

```
const int N = 100000;
const int SQRT_N = 316;

void shieve(char (&isNotPrime)[N])
{
    memset(isNotPrime, 0, N);
    isNotPrime[0] = 1; // 0 is not a prime
    isNotPrime[1] = 1; // 1 is not a prime
    // now remove all evens from 4 up
    for (int i = 4; i < N; i = i + 2) {
        isNotPrime[i] = 1; // remove evens
    }
    // now loop through remaing up to square root of max number
    for (int i = 3; i < SQRT_N; i = i + 2) {
        if (!isNotPrime[i]) {
            for(int j = i * i; j < N; j = j + 2 * i) {
                isNotPrime[j] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great stuff, it worked

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you should use constants instead of `#define`

```
#define RUNS 1000
```

should become

```
const int RUNS = 1000
```

---

Loop variables should be declared in the smallest scope possible, not at the top of the file.

---

Always use braces, the following line is not easy to modify:

```
if(z[i]==0) for(j=2*i;j<100000;j=j+i) z[j]=1;
```

---

```
using namespace std;
```

Is considered bad practice.

---

### Lack of modularization

All your code is **top level** , you should use more functions to facilitate reuse.

Comment: the question was for optimisation of the code to find primes faster, not optimisation of whole c++ structure.

Comment: @skwiot86 here reviewers are free to comment on every aspect of the code.

Answer (score 1):

### 1

At first, [do not use `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

### 2

You do not use any function from `"math.h"` header so you do not need to include it.

### 3

Next, using `#include <windows.h>` is also bad. You use it only for time measure. Standard `C++` library has a dedicated header for this purpouse. It will make code more portable. Example:

```
#include <chrono>

// ... some code

auto startTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

// do calculations

auto endTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

// output

auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(endTime - startTime).count();
std::cout << "Total time: " << duration << " milliseconds.";
```

### 4

[`main` function should always return `int`](https://blog.feabhas.com/2011/01/void-mainvoidthe-argument-continues/), and accepted arguments are either none or

```
(int, char* [])
```

### 5

Instead of `#define` macro, `C++` uses `const` keyword:

```
const int runs = 1000;
```

Comment: Your first and fifth point duplicate one of the already existing answers... Additionally I find your formatting somewhat over the top. Still: nice observations

Comment: @Vogel612 Was doing this on mobile, thus it was somehow tedious to make proper formatting. Also, I wanted to make it more complex - that's why my observations are duplicating.